# What happens to a relative path in a file added with \input{}?

Tags: include, input

I stumbled upon the following question:

In the preamble of my main tex file for my thesis, I've included several other files with definitions for abbreviations which are in the same path as **`main.tex`**, so I've only used the filename with the *relative path* to include them:

```
\include{abbrevations.tex}
```

For using some of my definitions also in other TeX-Documents (e. g. graphics created with IPE) I've created a file called **`IPE-Preamble.tex`**, which contains selected parts of my preamble, so also the lines `\include{abbrevations.tex}`.

Both mentioned files are located in the same path THESIS/

I've included the file `IPE-Preamble.tex` in many other files which are located in the path THESIS/graphics successfully, it works:

```
\input{/drive/path/path2/THESIS/IPE-Preamble.tex}
```

Now I wanted to use this file also in .tex files which are located elsewhere on the same computer (let's say path `/drive/path3/path4/main2.tex`). I used the same input command with the full path for IPE-Preamble as stated above, but I get an error message, that commands (which are defined in `abbreviations.tex` are "not defined", so it seems that the `include` command does not work in this case.

Does `TeX` search for the file `/drive/path3/path4/abbreviations.tex` because of the relative path of the `include` command in `IPE-Preamble.tex`?

Comment: Don't use \include for code snippets. \include is only useful for document parts like a complete chapter. In all other cases use \input. Regarding the relative pathes see the FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=docotherdir

Comment: `\include{abbrevations.tex}` is wrong it should be called without any extension: `\include{abbrevations}`. While `\input` can be used with and without (defaults to `.tex`) extension to load any kind of text file (e.g. `\lstinputlisting` is using it internally), `\include` is explicitly for `.tex` files only. If you use the extension a file `abbrevations.tex.aux` is created not `abbrevations.aux`. I'm not sure if and what issues that may cause.

Comment: You can also set the environment variable `TEXINPUT=".:/drive/path/path2/THESIS:"`, to make LaTeX look for files also there. I do this a lot for my thesis.

Comment: @Ulrike: :-) I actually have an `\include{abbrevations}` in my Ph.D. thesis, so I can just use `\includeonly` if I need to give that list to my supervisor as PDF. Same for the ToC etc. They all belong on pages of their own anyway. But you are of course right, that `\include` shouldn't be used for code snippets and only if you have a reason to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\include` causes an `.aux` file to be written in the same directory of the included file; the most recent TeX distributions disallow writing in directories called with an explicit path or above the directory where the main file resides.

Use `\input` that doesn't suffer from these limitations, provided you have read access to the directories.