# How to do multiple calls to \includeonly?

Tags: input, include

Doing multiple call to include only as:

```
\includeonly{myfirstinclude}
\includeonly{mysecondinclude}
```

It is only including the last file called `mysecondinclude` by the last `\includeonly` call. It is useful to do multiple calls to `\includeonly` when you have all your `\includeonly` call listed and commented out.

```
\documentclass{article}

% How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104159/how-does-filecontents-keep-latex
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myfirstinclude.tex}
myfirstinclude
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mysecondinclude.tex}
mysecondinclude
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mythirdinclude.tex}
mythirdinclude
\end{filecontents*}

% \includeonly{myfirstinclude}
% \includeonly{mysecondinclude}
% \includeonly{mythirdinclude}

\begin{document}

\include{myfirstinclude}
\include{mysecondinclude}
\include{mythirdinclude}

\end{document}
```

So when you want to include only one or some files, you just uncomment the desired line(s).

```
\includeonly{myfirstinclude}
\includeonly{mysecondinclude}
% \includeonly{mythirdinclude}
```

---

## Related Questions

1. [What happens to a relative path in a file added with \input{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22058/what-happens-to-a-relative-path-in-a-file-added-with-input)
2. [A variant of \includeonly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62904/a-variant-of-includeonly)
3. [How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files)
4. [subimport and includeonly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly)
5. [Using standalone to combine multiple .tex into a single file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320572/using-standalone-to-combine-multiple-tex-into-a-single-file)
6. [Can a file know if it has been \include'ed or \input'ed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27106/can-a-file-know-if-it-has-been-includeed-or-inputed)
7. [Generate a merged LaTeX file, with \input code in place?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/generate-a-merged-latex-file-with-input-code-in-place)
8. [How to merge several tex files so that they have one table of contents/List of tables & figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201898/how-to-merge-several-tex-files-so-that-they-have-one-table-of-contents-list-of-t)
9. [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)
10. [Options for building multiple documents from the same content with different layouts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13184/options-for-building-multiple-documents-from-the-same-content-with-different-lay)
11. [What state changes are caused by \input?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388437/what-state-changes-are-caused-by-input)

Comment: It should be said somewhere that the usual way to do this would be `\includeonly{myfirstinclude,mysecondinclude}`, which doesn't need any new macros.  The disadvantage is that you have to change the command manually instead of commenting out lines.  (You already know this, since `\addtoincludeonly` is building a comma separated list.  But if a TeX rookie finds this question, I would encourage them to start with the usual way before using your macro.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [your specific use case](http://xyproblem.info/) you could use just one `includeonly` by putting each chapter on its own line:

```
\includeonly{%
myfirstinclude,
mysecondinclude,
mythirdinclude,
}
```

This way it is easy to comment out any of them, say, the second one:

```
\includeonly{%
myfirstinclude,
%mysecondinclude,
mythirdinclude,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new command as `\addtoincludeonly{somefile}`, which holds an internal string as explained 
 on [Stringified commands to macros sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/stringified-commands-to-macros-sequence), then after all your custom include only calls, you do the call to another command as `\doincludeonly`, which takes no arguments.

The new commnad `\doincludeonly` is required as we only should do a call to `\includeonly` when some call to `\addtoincludeonly{somefile}` is performed. Otherwise an empty call as `includeonly{}` will create an almost empty document not including anything inserted/added by `\include{somefile}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104159/how-does-filecontents-keep-latex
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Logical String Length
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87638/logical-string-length
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\includeonlyfilelist}[0]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtoincludeonly}[1]
{%
    \StrLen{\includeonlyfilelist}[\includeonlyfilelistlen]

    % How to concatenate strings into a single command?
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/how-to-concatenate-strings-into-a
    \ifnum\includeonlyfilelistlen>0
        \g@addto@macro\includeonlyfilelist{,#1}
    \else
        \g@addto@macro\includeonlyfilelist{#1}
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\doincludeonly}[0]
{%
    \StrLen{\includeonlyfilelist}[\includeonlyfilelistlen]
    \ifnum\includeonlyfilelistlen>0
        \includeonly{\includeonlyfilelist}
    \else
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{myfirstinclude.tex}
myfirstinclude
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mysecondinclude.tex}
mysecondinclude
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mythirdinclude.tex}
mythirdinclude
\end{filecontents*}

\addtoincludeonly{myfirstinclude}
\addtoincludeonly{mysecondinclude}
% \addtoincludeonly{mythirdinclude}
\doincludeonly

\begin{document}

\include{myfirstinclude}
\include{mysecondinclude}
\include{mythirdinclude}

\end{document}
```

---

## References

1. [Using string variable with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/using-string-variable-with-latex)
2. [How to concatenate strings into a single command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/how-to-concatenate-strings-into-a-single-command)
3. [Stringified commands to macros sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/stringified-commands-to-macros-sequence)
4. [How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104159/how-does-filecontents-keep-latex-parsing-while-temporarily-stop-writing-output)
5. [How to form "if ... or ... then" conditionals in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/how-to-form-if-or-then-conditionals-in-tex)
6. [Logical String Length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87638/logical-string-length)
7. [How to append data to a global string variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290711/how-to-append-data-to-a-global-string-variable)